# align image and header and subtitle in html table

Tags: html, css

I have a table and am placing the image, header,link and description in the td. I want the format like this as attached (file image). I tried the following but the alignment is not proper.[image]

My **html** code:

```
<section class="sub-section" id="test">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td> <img src="../img/img.png" /> </td>
         <td class="tdalignmiddle">Header</td>
         <td class="tdalignmiddle">Link</td>
         <td class="tdalignbottom">Description</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.table{
}

.tdalignmiddle {

    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    font-size:25px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.tdalignbottom {

    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: left;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
table tr td{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="sub-section" id="test">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="../img/img.png" />
            </td>
            <td><h3>Header</h3><a href="#">Link</a><p>Description</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</section>
```

Then you can adjust as your needs  on the `<h3>` , `<a>` and `<p>` by setting a class ex: `<h3 class="title">Header</h3>`

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/a5c7fo9c/18/)**

Comment: I am not getting beside the image. It is coming below the image. First column, i need the image, second column header, third column link and fourth column below i need the description as shown in the image attached.

Comment: i need the link beside the Header and not beneath it. How would that need to be aligned?

Comment: Set `display:inline-block` to both elements `<h3>` e `<a>` -https://jsfiddle.net/a5c7fo9c/20/